# time format for cat output in r

Tags: r, date, time

I am writing to a text file using `cat`

```
mytime <- structure(
  1465667039, 
  class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), 
  tzone = "UTC"
)
sink("text.txt")
cat(mytime)
sink()
```

The output is `1465667039`. I want format as `("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")` and the output should look like `2016-06-11 17:43:59`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using `as.character(mytime)` makes desired output.

Comment: But the time zone has disappeared.

Comment: @JASC That's not what was asked for, but it sounds like you need ```format(...,usetz=TRUE)```.